# How can I add custom fields in checkout page?

Tags: php, magento2.4.2

I want add two fields in checkout page (text type). How can I do this in Magento 2.4.2?

Answer (score 1):

for add custom fields on the checkout page please refer below links:

- [https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-checkout-field/#:~:text=A%20custom%20checkout%20field%20in,party%20%E2%80%9COrder%20Attributes%E2%80%9D%20extension](https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-checkout-field/#:%7E:text=A%20custom%20checkout%20field%20in,party%20%E2%80%9COrder%20Attributes%E2%80%9D%20extension).
- https://blog.magezon.com/how-to-add-field-in-magento-2-checkout-page-mgt/
- https://bsscommerce.com/blog/add-magento-custom-checkout-fields/

Answer (score 1):

Try this all step it will be very useful to you

1.Create a custom module:
Create a directory structure for your custom module. Let's assume the module name is "Custom_CheckoutFields". Place it in the **app/code** directory.

2.Define module structure:
Create the necessary files to define the module. In the module's root directory (app/code/Custom/CheckoutFields/registration.php)

registration.php:

```
 <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_CheckoutFields',
    __DIR__
);
```

module.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_CheckoutFields" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

3.Create a layout file:
Create the layout file (checkout_index_index.xml) in the following location: app/code/Custom/CheckoutFields/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_CheckoutFields/checkout/custom-checkout-fields</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

4.Create template file:
Create the template file (custom-checkout-fields.html) in the following location: app/code/Custom/CheckoutFields/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/custom-checkout-fields.html.

```
 <div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="field1">Field 1</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="field1" id="field1" data-bind="value: getField1Value()" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

5.Run necessary commands: Run the following commands from your Magento root directory to update the system:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps,

1.Create a di.xml in this path app/code/CompanyName/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Use this plugin at app\code\CompanyName\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php

   ```
   <?PHP
     namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout;
     class LayoutProcessor
     {
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom-field'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
            'label' => 'Custom Field',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ];


        return $jsLayout;
    }}
   ```

[image]